# Box.com Get Request RestSharp C#

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I have a problem where my POST request returns back a token but when I change my code to use the token and try a GET request, it gives me a "Status:0" message. Am I writing this code wrong? I've tried adding "Bearer " + token to the Authentication.

ErrorException = {"Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."}

Post:

var client = new RestClient("https://api.box.com/oauth2/token");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.Post };

```
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("client_id", $"{client_ID}");
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", $"{client_secret}");
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        request.AddParameter("box_subject_type", "enterprise");
        request.AddParameter("box_subject_id", enterpriseID);

        var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        var responseMessage = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
```

GET:

```
            var client2 = new RestClient("https://api.box.com/2.0/files/154072314030");
            var request2 = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.Get };

            request2.AddHeader("Authorization",  token);
            request2.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var response2 = await client2.ExecuteAsync(request2);
            var responseMessage2 = JObject.Parse(response2.Content);
```

Comment: While you already solved it by using the SDK. The error in your above code is the usage of the wrong method verb (as the error states). In your code you should use `{ Method = Method.Post }` to send the body, cause on a GET request a body is forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using their SDK. This is how I was able to login and pull the items in the folder:

BoxFolder folderWithLink = new BoxFolder();
BoxSharedLinkRequest linkRequest = new BoxSharedLinkRequest();

```
        int offset = 0;
        int count = 0;
        string folderID = "";

        //create connection to Box.com
        var boxConfig = new BoxConfigBuilder("CLIENT ID", "CLIENT SECRET", "Enterprise ID", "PRIVATE KEY", "PRIVATE KEY PASSWORD", "PUBLIC KEY ID").Build();
        var boxJWT = new BoxJWTAuth(boxConfig);
        var adminToken = await boxJWT.AdminTokenAsync();
        var client = boxJWT.AdminClient(adminToken);


        //Get the parent folder information and find the Batch folderID
        while (folderID == "")
        {
            var batches = await client.FoldersManager.GetFolderItemsAsync("FOLDER ID", 250, offset);
            foreach (var batchEntry in batches.Entries)
            {
                Console.Writeline(Batch.Name);
            }
```